# How to import a unity package that was build in windows to mac os?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Bought a unity asset package in a unofficial store. It's supposed to be a unitypackage but by macbook sees it as just a folder and I can't import it. The package was build on a windows computer. So, should I convert it some how? Or is there a way to import it as it is?

Answer (score 2):

Unity packages work with any OS.

> Bought a unity asset package in an unofficial store. It's supposed to be a unitypackage but my MacBook sees it as just a folder and I can't import it.

The package should have a .unitypackage extension, if it doesn't have that extension either you have to move the folder to Project/Assets, or accept that you have been scammed